# Как правильно установить vue-cli?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vue.js

Всем привет. Пытаюсь воспользоваться vue-cli под winows7. Устанавливаю его (npm install -g vue-cli) и командой vue не могу инициализировать проект, так как команда vue не распознается.

```
D:\test-tasks\test-vue-cli>npm i -g vue-cli

C:\Users\Smirnov.Denis\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue -> C:\Users\Smirnov.Denis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\bin\vue
C:\Users\Smirnov.Denis\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue-list -> C:\Users\Smirnov.Denis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\bin\vue-list
C:\Users\Smirnov.Denis\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue-init -> C:\Users\Smirnov.Denis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\bin\vue-init
C:\Users\Smirnov.Denis\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue-build -> C:\Users\Smirnov.Denis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\bin\vue-build
C:\Users\Smirnov.Denis\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- vue-cli@2.8.1

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\vue-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

D:\test-tasks\test-vue-cli>vue
"vue" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Почему так происходит? Быть может проблема в правах?

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему, с помощью человека с другого ресурса.
Было необходимо добавить в системную переменную PATH C:\Users\Smirnov.Denis\AppData\Roaming\npm\ . Как я понял, vue-cli без этого не видел пути к исполняемым файлам.

Comment: Система не видела команды vue, а ты указал путь где искать эту команду и остальные, по факту если ты теперь поставишь глобально в npm еще какие то команды они все будут работать

Answer (score 0):

Возможно нет папки `node_modules`
Выполни: `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно умтановить сам vue глобально, в системе.

Comment: А если вопрос прочитать?

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще небольшой нюанс.
Может так получиться, что yarn будет устанавливать глобальные зависимости в разные с npm папки. Тут тоже надо ковыряться с путями, куда конкретно он их кладет.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/739753)

Answer (score -1):

npm install -g @vue/cli
потом перейти в консоле в свою папку cd /papka
дальше напиши
 vue create . (дальше выбери пакеты котрые тебе нада vuex/router ....)

и перед npm пиши sudo

Comment: Зачем переходить? И в какой он сейчас?

Answer (score -3):

Это означает что у вас не установлен `vue`.

```
npm i -g vue
```

Comment: Нет, не означает. `vue` зависимость `vue-cli`, если `vue-cli` успешно установился (о чём говорит вывод), то и `vue` тоже.

Answer (score -5):

В терминале пишеш `gitclone https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli.git` и все

Comment: А если не установлен vue пропишите "sudo npm install vue"